# Love2D / LUA Problem with object not keeping values it was created with

Tags: oop, lua, love2d

I'm new to Löve2D and Lua and am trying to learn by making a little game.
I've googled a bit and found the same solution to classes and objects, but I'm still not sure what I'm doing. I put my class definition in a "module" - a separate file and require it from my main file.

Here is the code in my module:

```
-- Meta class
Asterisk =  {
                id = nil,
                x = 0,
                y = 0,
                growth = 1,
                connections = {},
                color = { 0, 1, 0 },
                radius = 20,
                segments = 20
            }

-- Base class method new
function Asterisk:new ( o, id, x, y )
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable ( o, self )
    self.__index = self
    self.id = id
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    return o
end
return Asterisk
```

In my main.lua file i have to explicitly re-set the values I set while constructing the objects. Also the default values are not being set when the object is constructed...

```
function love.load ()
  Star = require "Asterisk"
  stars = {
            Star:new ( nil, 1, 300, 600 ),
            Star:new ( nil, 2, 400, 200 )
          }

  stars[1].x = 300
  stars[1].y = 600
  stars[2].x = 400
  stars[2].y = 200

  love.window.setFullscreen ( true, "desktop" )
  love.graphics.setColor ( 0.5, 0.01, 0.9 )

end
```

Thank you all!

---

Following @Egor-Skriptunoff's advice I changed my code to the following. Also assigning the default values like this gives me the functionality I am looking for! Does anyone see any side effects I don't?

```
function Star:new ( o, id, x, y )
    local o = o or {}
    setmetatable ( o, self )
    self.__index = self
    o.id = id or Star.id
    o.x = x or Star.x
    o.y = y or Star.y
    o.growth = Star.growth
    ...
```

Comment: Inside `function Asterisk:new()` replace `self.id = id` with `o.id = id`, the same with x and y.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! The default values still don't work, but I get that I can set them in the function Asterisk:new just as I set x, y and id

Comment: @nodFlindors default values should work if you do what Egor suggested

Comment: @Nifim well yes it does, concerning my misunderstanding what `self` refers to. 
I did add to my question what I changed in the function `:new` to get the behavior I want. :)